# Why is the missing TabController using TabBar in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I started writing the TabController _tabController  and initializing it in initState(), using the controller in the TabBar to introduce the TabController, but the Debug show : No TabController for TabBarView.

```
I/flutter ( 4328): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 4328): The following assertion was thrown building MediaQuery(MediaQueryData(size: Size(411.4, 683.4),

I/flutter ( 4328): devicePixelRatio: 2.6, textScaleFactor: 1.0, platformBrightness: Brightness.light, padding:
I/flutter ( 4328): EdgeInsets.zero, viewInsets: EdgeInsets.zero, alwaysUse24HourFormat: false, accessibleNavigation:
I/flutter ( 4328): falsedisableAnimations: falseinvertColors: falseboldText: false)):

I/flutter ( 4328): No TabController for TabBarView.
I/flutter ( 4328): When creating a TabBarView, you must either provide an explicit TabController using the "controller"
I/flutter ( 4328): property, or you must ensure that there is a DefaultTabController above the TabBarView.
I/flutter ( 4328): In this case, there was neither an explicit controller nor a default controller.
```

```
class _ScaffoldRouteState extends State<ScaffoldRoute> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

  TabController  _tabController;
  List tabs;

 void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // 创建Controller  
     tabs = ['news','history','picture'];
    _tabController = TabController(length: tabs.length, vsync: this);
  }


  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title:Text('The App By Scaffold'),
        bottom: TabBar(   //生成Tab菜单
            controller: _tabController,
            tabs: tabs.map((e) => Tab(text: e)).toList(),  
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Your code works for me. Did you do a hot restart instead of a hot reload, when introducing the _tabController? You could also try "flutter clean" in the terminal and try rerunning the code afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for your help has been solved through flutter clean

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your code as well and it works.

[image]

Output:

[image]

Logs:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.1, on macOS 11.2.1 20D75 darwin-x64, locale en)
    • Flutter version 2.0.1 at /Users/user/Developer/flutter
    • Framework revision c5a4b4029c (2 weeks ago), 2021-03-04 09:47:48 -0800
    • Engine revision 40441def69
    • Dart version 2.12.0

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /Users/user/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.2
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 12.0.1, Build version 12A7300
    • CocoaPods version 1.10.0

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.53.2)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.20.0

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • sdk gphone x86 arm (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x86    • Android 11 (API 30) (emulator)
    • Chrome (web)                • chrome        • web-javascript • Google Chrome 89.0.4389.90

• No issues found!
```

In the comment, it seems that your issue was resolved using `flutter clean`. That would be effective since it's getting rid of some memory issues. The command actually reduces the project size of your sample app by deleting the build directory and some other files. Your pc might consumed a lot of memory in the past while testing some flutter projects that you've created.

Also, if you are not really sure whats the wrong with your code. You can try to run it in [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/flutter).

Here, I run your code in there and it gives the same output:

[image]